# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (n^2+q^k)^{-s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $q>1$. For which $s \in \mathbb C$ does
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (n^2+q^k)^{-s}$$
converge?

I hope the $q^k$ grows so fast that it might have not a too big infuence so that we actually have to care about
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2s} = \zeta(2s)$$
where we have convergence for $\Re(s)>1/2$. But here I need a rigorous argument.